# Problem accessing 4d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 4d vector and I am trying to add values to it. I don't receive any compiler errors, but when running it, the program freezes when it gets to the line where I am adding values to this vector.

I initialize the vector in a header file like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > > _celllist;
```

The array is then sized with the following:

```
_celllist.resize(_vnx);
 for(int i=0;i<_vnx;i++) 
    {
        //y axis size
        _celllist[i].resize(_vny);
            for(int j=0;j<_vny;j++)
            {
                //z axis size
                _celllist[i][j].resize(_vnz);
            }
    }
```

This line then causes the program to crash:

```
_celllist[ix][iy][iz].push_back(i);
```

Note that ix, iy, and iz are all int and i is an unsigned int.

Can anyone see what might be going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: what are the values of ix iy iz and i?

Comment: The other dimensions may be empty, but you neglected to share that portion.  Can you include a full, minimal example?

Comment: @Gabe, _celllist is not a pointer, `_celllist = new ...` would be illegal.

Comment: @Gabe It's a stack-allocated `vector` object, not a pointer to a `vector`. There's no need for `new`.

Comment: @Kyle, can you break right before that line and tell us the values of ix, iy, iz, i, and _vnx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5B%5D/)[] does not expand or guarantee that the element is valid.  It's a faster version of [at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/at/) with little or no error checking:

Convert your code to the safer version for now:

```
_celllist.at(ix).at(iy).at(iz).push_back(i);
```

This new code will throw an out_of_range exception if your indices are off.

Comment: It was an out of bounds error. Thanks for this version. I will use this to help figure out why it is out of bounds.

Comment: Right, you also should reconsider whether `std::vector` is the right thing for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because celllist[ix] doesn't exist because nothing has been pushed back into it.  You're pushing back i in to the 4th nested vector when the 4th nested vector has to be contained as an element as the 3rd, contained as the 2nd, etc.

**More Clearly**

vector > v;

I can't do:

```
v[0].push_back(1);
```

Until I do:

```
v.push_back(vector<int>());
```

But now that I have done that,

```
v[0]
```

is actually an element of v that is a vector itself.  So I can access it and do push back like:

```
v[0].push_back(7);
```

Comment: I think a recent edit added code, because the code shows that all the vectors already exist.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess I would say that you doing out of bounds accesses of your array. When you do `_celllist[ix][iy][iz].push_back(i)` is `_celllist.size() > ix`, is `_celllist[ix].size() > iy`, is `_celllist[ix][iy].size() > iz`? Unless all these things are true your program will not work.

Comment: @Kyle: add `assert(ix<_celllist.size() && iy<_celllist[ix].size() && iz<_celllist[ix][iy].size()` right before the line that crashes. If it stops on the assert, you know that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is probably caused by out of bounds access on your vectors. Note, that `std::vector::operator[]` does not check bounds! Though `std::vector::at()` does.

`std::vector` is probably not the thing you want. Of course you can use nested `std::vector` like this, but remember that this will not create 4d matrixes as you think. `std::vector` just manages a dynamic array in contiguous memory.

Maybe you will be happier with plain C nested arrays, e.g. `unsigned int[XDIM][YDIM][ZDIM]`.